# Post xml to PHP for validation against xsd with XMLHttpRequest or Ajax?

Tags: php, xml, validation, post, xsd

I have a flash application that posts xml to a php page which validates it against an xsd schema. I'm trying to do the same thing but from an html page. I'm using XMLHttpRequest or with jquery's ajax call but I keep running around the same issues. "document has no document" or the "access-control-allow-origin' header issue. I can fix one but not the other.

My PHP page looks like this:

```
function libxml_append_errors() { 
    global $returnXML, $errors;
    $e = libxml_get_errors(); 
    foreach ($e as $error) { 
        $en = $returnXML->createElement("error", trim($error->message)); 
        $en->setAttribute('line',$error->line);
        $errors->appendChild($en);
    } 
    libxml_clear_errors(); 
} 

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 


$xml = new DOMDocument();
$contents = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
$xml->loadXML($contents);


$returnXML = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$rootNode = $returnXML->createElement("result");
$returnXML->appendChild($rootNode);

$errors = $returnXML->createElement("errors");

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('muffin_dumplings.xsd')) 
{   
    libxml_append_errors(); 
} 
$rootNode->appendChild($errors);
echo $returnXML->saveXML();
```

Either way I'm looking to get xml back with any validation errors or a simple empty error xml node same as I do with flash.

Comment: It feels like things are so close to being working I just can't see why Flash is so magical to read the right response but using simple JS cannot.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares, here is the answer. When you post to PHP, have the right headers, and are using ajax you need to pass a content type. Then it works.